# The quadraphonic speakers stay silent

Tags: audio, speakers, surround-sound

So I have two amplifiers set up, one plugged in the normal R/L speaker output and the other one in the subwoofer/center output. I've got speakers connected to each amp and have confirmation they both work by using my phone on them (with the same cables too).

But here's the thing: I can only hear the front speakers. The subwoofer stays silent. I've tried everything: Realtek, switching amplifiers, cranking the volume up, putting the other speakers as Side L/R, every option in the settings, nothing works. I am certain that I am using the right outputs as they are labelled on my computer.

What could the solution be? Is there a program that could let me place the speakers just like I want?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your system, the sound card, the hookup, the signal source for the subwoofer/center output.  The center speaker works?  Have you verified the subwoofer works connected to the amp (sounds like you verified the amp is working but not clear about the subwoofer)?

Comment: Yes, the subwoofer works with my phone. The soundcard is the default soundcard, nothing special and I already gave my hook-up (two amps each connected to speakers, both 100% functional). The problem is software.

Comment: Have you hooked speakers directly to the computer outputs and verified whether a signal is being sent on the subwoofer output?  Is the output dead silent or can you hear any sound (like AC hum)?

Comment: Are you actually trying to use the setup as dual stereo, or some kind of 'fake' 5.1. If you are set to quad, the sub & centre channels won't be active, only the front & rear LR. Side LR will only be active in 7.1

Comment: There's nothing in the subwoofer. Like absolutely nothing when the volume is at max.
I tried quad and 5.1 and both make both outputs silent (RR and RL and Sub and Center)